# Overriding Omniauth key/secret combinations from a controller in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, twitter, omniauth, linkedin-api

I have an Omniauth setup in rails, with a regular omniauth.rb configuration file in config/initializers, for example:

```
    provider :twitter, :setup => lambda { |env|
      twitter_key = keychain.key "twitter"
      twitter_secret = keychain.secret "twitter"

      Rails.application.config.twitter_key = twitter_key
      Rails.application.config.twitter_secret = twitter_secret
      env['omniauth.strategy'].options[:consumer_key] = twitter_key
      env['omniauth.strategy'].options[:consumer_secret] = twitter_secret}
```

This works fine, but I want to be able to override this key/secret combination with a different one from a controller in my application. How would I go about doing this?

I've been searching for quite some time without success. Hopefully this is specific enough.

Answer (score 0):

On your omniauth.rb, do this:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :twitter,:setup => true
end
```

Then on your controller you have to define the following:

```
def setup
 request.env['omniauth.strategy'].options[:consumer_key] = @site.twitter_key
 request.env['omniauth.strategy'].options[:consumer_secret] = @site.twitter_secret
 render :text => "Setup complete.", :status => 404
end
```

Of course you have to add the associated routes, on your routes.rb.

```
  #Twitter Omniauth routes
  match '/auth/twitter/callback' => 'session#authorize_callback'
  match '/auth/twitter/setup' => 'session#setup'
```

Good luck

Regards.
Ivan.

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but it doesn't seem to work in my current setup. `request.env['omniauth.strategy']` is nil to me in the controller. This was the same issue I was having in previous attempts! Is there anything I should have to do in the config to make it available.